# how to read data of composite class object from file using readObject()?

Tags: java

how to read data of composite object from file using readObject()?
My code is below and i got output as

```
version=4
purpose is DEMO
value=4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Serializations.readObj(PS_Task3.java:39)
        at PS_Task3.main(PS_Task3.java:46)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

//PS_Task3.java
//this is the code i have tried to execute. i got correct output when i remove variable of type demo in SerializationDemo . but NullPointerException when i tried for composite class. 
please help me..thanks in advance

```
import java.io.*;
class SerializationDemo implements Serializable //composite class
{
public int value = 4;
public demo d1;
public String purpose="DEMO";
public int getValue(){
    return value;
}
}
class demo{
    private int demoval;
    demo(){
        demoval=10;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return demoval;
    }
}
class Serializations {
    void writeObj()throws IOException{   //writes into file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("temp1.bin");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        SerializationDemo sd = new SerializationDemo();
        oos.writeObject(sd);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    }
    void readObj()throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException{ //reads from file
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("temp1.bin");
        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        SerializationDemo sd = (SerializationDemo) oin.readObject();
        System.out.println("version="+sd.value);
        System.out.println("purpose is "+sd.purpose);
        System.out.println("value="+sd.getValue());
        System.out.println("value="+sd.d1.getValue());
    }
}    
public class PS_Task3{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException {
        Serializations s = new Serializations();
        s.writeObj();
        s.readObj();  //here i got the error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the serialization mechanism to work all of your classes local member variables must be primitive types, or serializable objects.

The first problem is that `SerializationDemo` has a member variable of of type `demo` that is not serializable.

This should fix that problem:

```
class demo implements Serializable{
    private int demoval;
    demo(){
        demoval=10;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return demoval;
    }
}
```

The second problem that is causing the null exception is that you never set the value of `d1`. Make sure you set it before you serialize it, or else when you try to deserialize it you will be trying to make an instance of the demo class from null. Easy fix is to add default constructor:

```
import java.io.*;
class SerializationDemo implements Serializable //composite class
{
    public SerializationDemo()
    {
        d1 = new demo();
    }
    public int value = 4;
    public demo d1;
    public String purpose="DEMO";
    public int getValue(){
    return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check is there any `null`

```
void readObj()throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException{ //reads from file
       try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("temp1.bin");
        System.out.println("1->"+fis==null);
        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        System.out.println("2->"+oin==null);
        SerializationDemo sd = (SerializationDemo) oin.readObject();
        System.out.println("3->"+sd==null);
        System.out.println("version="+sd.value);
        System.out.println("purpose is "+sd.purpose);
        System.out.println("value="+sd.getValue());
        System.out.println("value="+sd.d1.getValue());
       }catch(Exception e)
         {
          System.out.println(e.toString);}
    }
```

Please check that where is actually getting null, then take action there.